# Polymer 2.0 getting paper-input file

Tags: file, input, polymer

I am using Polymer 2.0.  I have a

```
<paper-input type="file" id"myFile"></paper-input>
```

Once I selected a file I want to use Polymer (javascript) to get the reference and details of the file.  Previously I had used

```
this.$.myFile.inputElement.files[0];
```

But that doesn't seem to work now, it says undefined.  Please help me access the file.  Here is a jsbin:

https://jsbin.com/luledugege/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.$.myFile.inputElement.inputElement.files[0]
```

*paper-input* has attribute inputElement to get its *iron-input*. And this element has, in turn, the native input in its shadow root with files attribute.

Your input could be:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">

<dom-module id="my-paper-input-file">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    <paper-input type="file" id="myFile" on-change="_handleFiles"></paper-input>

  </template>

  <script>
    class MyPaperInputFile extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() { return 'my-paper-input-file'; }

      static properties() {

        files: Object

      }

      _handleFiles(e) {
        this.files = this.$.myFile.inputElement.inputElement.files;
        //SAME: this.files = e.target.inputElement.inputElement.files;
      }

    }

    window.customElements.define(MyPaperInputFile.is, MyPaperInputFile);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```